# How to treat deprecations as errors based on their message in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deprecated

I was wondering if I can treat a deprecation with a specific message as an error? Say I'm trying to cut out some part of the codebase so I added `DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("my custom message")`. Now I'd like to treat only these custom deprecations as errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script run at the build phase which I think will do what you want called 'todoToWarning.sh' :

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

This tags all my "TODO:" as Warnings in Xcode. So simply replace the TAGS with your identifiers and change the 'warning' to 'error' on the last line. Then add the "Run Script" to your build phase and build the project!